# Can't reference JPAApi

Tags: hibernate, playframework

This is my build.sbt

```
name := "untitled"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `untitled` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.5.Final",
  javaJdbc , cache , javaWs , "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36")

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )
```

I want to use Hibernate with `Play Framework 2.4.2`. My plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.2")
```

I'm trying to access JPAApi but the IDE isn't recognizing it. Any idea what imports I'm missing?

Apologize if this sounds trivial but I just spent a couple of hours trying to achieve something to no avail.

Comment: Your config looks okay to me. You access JPA with `JPA.em().` right? E.g. `JPA.em().merge(yourEntity)`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently my sbt file is fine, this might sound silly but what fixed the problem is reloading IntelliJ, now it sees all the classes and I can reference the new `JPAApi`